# Calculate Local Velocity of a body at a specific point unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, physics, game-physics

I'm trying to create custom vehicle physics system, without using built in wheel collider.

I have a Cube (rigidbody) with 4 points acting as suspension points (Wheel Location Points). I want to calculate velocity of these points along its local x-axis so that I can apply sideways frictional forces to the rigid body in order to stop it from moving sideways.

```
// previousSuspensionPoint (Transform) is a global variable in the script
// that holds the previous position of the suspension point
//
// suspensionPoint (Transform) is the current position of the suspension point

// If the position of the suspension point changes, calculate the velocity of that point
if (previousSuspensionPoint.position.x != suspensionPoints.position.x)
{
    // Calculating the velocity of the point
    sidewaysVelocity = (previousSuspensionPoint.position.x - suspensionPoints.position.x) / Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    Debug.Log("sideWayVelocity: " + sidewaysVelocityFront[i]);

    previousSuspensionPoint = suspensionPoints;
}
```

This code calculates the velocity according to global axes. I want to calculate in local axes of the point

Comment: Well... Feel free to do so, I guess... What is your question here? You should edit some code of yourself into the question to show what you have tried. And welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Thanks @geisterfurz007. Question Edited.